# r markdown biblio-style does not work

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bibliography

I have some troubles of changing the citation style of bibliography in my thesis. According to [r-markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/citations.html) to specify the bib style (I need `acm` from [latex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles)) I just need to do the following:

```
---
title: "title"
bibliography: biblioteka.bib
biblio-style: acm
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

However, the `biblio-style: acm` seems to have no influences on the citation style.

---

**current citation**:

random forest has been already applied in credit scoring `[@author1]` ...

```
@Article{author1,
   Title                   = {some title},
   Author                  = {Einstein},
   Year                    = {1997}
}
```

---

**desired output**:

random forest has been already applied in credit scoring `[1]` ...

```
References
[1] Einstein, some title, 1997
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility which works best for me is to add a [Citation Style Language (CSL)](http://citationstyles.org/) file - in your case a acm.csl - and refer to it in the YAML header. Open your text editor and copy following XML-Code into it, save it into your working directory and rename it to "acm.csl".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl" class="in-text" version="1.0" demote-non-dropping-particle="sort-only" default-locale="en-US">
  <info>
    <title>ACM SIGCHI Proceedings (2016)</title>
    <id>http://www.zotero.org/styles/acm-sigchi-proceedings</id>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/acm-sigchi-proceedings" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://cscw.acm.org/2016/submit/sigchi-word-proceedings.zip" rel="documentation"/>
    <author>
      <name>Yevgeniy Medynskiy</name>
      <email>eugenem@gatech.edu</email>
    </author>
    <contributor>
      <name>Sebastian Karcher</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Eric Baumer</name>
      <email>ebaumer@ics.uci.edu</email>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Svetlana Yarosh</name>
      <email>lana@cc.gatech.edu</email>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Lilly Irani</name>
      <email>lirani@ics.uci.edu</email>
    </contributor>
    <category citation-format="numeric"/>
    <category field="engineering"/>
    <updated>2012-09-27T22:06:38+00:00</updated>
    <rights license="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>
  </info>
  <macro name="author">
    <group suffix=".">
      <names variable="author">
        <name delimiter=", " and="text" sort-separator=", "/>
        <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
        <substitute>
          <names variable="editor"/>
        </substitute>
      </names>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="editor">
    <names variable="editor">
      <name delimiter=", " and="text" delimiter-precedes-last="never"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=")"/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="title">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song" match="any">
        <text variable="title" font-style="italic"/>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text variable="title"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="year">
    <date variable="issued">
      <date-part name="year"/>
    </date>
  </macro>
  <macro name="journal">
    <group delimiter=", ">
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
        <text variable="volume"/>
      </group>
      <text variable="issue"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="edition">
    <choose>
      <if is-numeric="edition">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
          <text term="edition" form="short"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text variable="edition"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="book-publisher">
    <group delimiter=", ">
      <text variable="publisher"/>
      <text variable="publisher-place"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="access">
    <choose>
      <if variable="DOI">
        <text variable="DOI" prefix="https://doi.org/"/>
      </if>
      <else-if variable="URL">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <text term="retrieved" text-case="capitalize-first"/>
          <date variable="accessed" form="text"/>
          <text term="from"/>
          <text variable="URL"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <citation collapse="citation-number">
    <sort>
      <key variable="citation-number"/>
    </sort>
    <layout prefix="[" suffix="]" delimiter=",">
      <group delimiter=":">
        <text variable="citation-number"/>
        <text variable="locator"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography second-field-align="flush" entry-spacing="0">
    <sort>
      <key macro="author"/>
      <key variable="issued"/>
    </sort>
    <layout>
      <text variable="citation-number" suffix="."/>
      <group delimiter=". " suffix=". ">
        <text macro="author"/>
        <text macro="year"/>
        <text macro="title"/>
      </group>
      <group suffix=".">
        <choose>
          <if type="bill book graphic legal_case legislation motion_picture report song thesis" match="any">
            <text macro="book-publisher" suffix="."/>
          </if>
          <else-if type="paper-conference">
            <group suffix="." delimiter=", ">
              <group delimiter=" ">
                <text term="in" text-case="capitalize-first"/>
                <group delimiter=" ">
                  <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
                  <text variable="collection-title" prefix="(" suffix=")"/>
                </group>
              </group>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
          </else-if>
          <else-if type="chapter" match="any">
            <group delimiter=" ">
              <text term="in" text-case="capitalize-first"/>
              <group delimiter=", ">
                <group delimiter=" ">
                  <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
                  <text macro="edition" prefix="(" suffix=")"/>
                </group>
                <text macro="editor"/>
              </group>
            </group>
            <group suffix="." delimiter=", " prefix=". ">
              <text macro="book-publisher"/>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
          </else-if>
          <else-if type="article-journal">
            <group suffix="." delimiter=": ">
              <text macro="journal"/>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
          </else-if>
          <else>
            <group suffix="." delimiter=", ">
              <group delimiter=" " font-style="italic">
                <text variable="container-title"/>
                <text variable="volume"/>
              </group>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </group>
      <text macro="access" prefix=" "/>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

After that refer in your YAML Header to this file:

```
---
title: "title"
bibliography: biblioteka.bib
csl: acm.csl
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

In order to change the style, just find another citation style at the [CSL-Website](http://citationstyles.org/) and proceed accordingly with a different *.csl.

For the sake of completeness, at the end of your thesis you need to add the bibliography:

````
# References
```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
# PrintBibliography(bib) 
```
````

Comment: hey jaySf, i need your help! i just noticed that multiple authors are presented as `et al` in the references instead of reiterating all of them

`[51] Ong, C.S. et al. 2005. title. journal. 29 (1), (2005), 41–47.`

here is a piece from the bib file. so the output should be instead of `et al.`, it give all the names of co-authors. can you please help on that?

`@Article{ong2005,
    Title = {title},
    Author = {Ong, C. S. and Huanga, J. J. and Tzeng, G. H.},
    Year = {2005},
    Journal = {journal},
    Volume = {29 (1)}
}`

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I could reproduce the issue but not when I was using my own apa.csl. Hence I assumed that the initial acm.csl was flawed and found one which seems to be working fine. I've edited the code in my answer accordingly.