# Rmarkdown does not have bibliography style effect

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bibliography

Does `biblio-style` work when used in the Rmd file? I could see an [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45903213/4836511) to provide external style file. But, I would like to know what does it require for `biblio-style` to work? I could not identify relevant notes on the usage of this: different styles available for usage.

```
---
title: "Analysis"
date: "27 October 2017"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
bibliography: bibliography.bib
biblio-style: acm
---
```

Does it only works while rendering books using the `bookdown` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblio-style` option only works for LaTeX/PDF output. It has no effect on HTML output. To specify the bibliography style of the latter, you have to use [the `csl` option](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#citation_styles).