# What choices can we set for the biblio-style parameter in the yaml header in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bibliography

I am trying to write a paper with the `rmarkdown` and `knitr` package.
When I set the bibliography style in the yaml header in the rmarkdown file, I am kind of wondering what choices do we have in hand for rmarkdown.

The default parameter given by the example in [bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latexpdf.html) is "apalike", which is obviously the APA style.

I am asking what choices do we have for this biblio-style parameter? For example, what parameter should I set to biblio-style if I want to use the Chicago style?

I googled this but it seems that no official document has been released on how to set this parameter. Thanks.

Comment: The argument is passed to `\bibliographystyle`. At least those: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles

Comment: @ Martin Schmelzer Gotch. Thanks for your information.

Comment: you can use any style with a csl file. Add something like `csl: journal-of-paleolimnology.csl` to your YAML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r markdown biblio-style does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902939/r-markdown-biblio-style-does-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes add `csl: yourbibliofile.csl` and not `biblio-style: yourfile.csl` as usual
Then it will be take into account.
You can find csl file at this website :https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByName/

Comment: Thanks for commenting!